# Why can't I add methods inside onCreate() because of annotation?

Tags: android

I have a problem with these method these methods to set default values use

```
 @SuppressLint("StringFormatMatches")
public void setTipValues() {

   tvTipPercent.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipPercent, Percentage));
    tvBillTotalAmount.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_billTotalResult,finalBillAmount));
    tvTipAmount.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipTotal,tipTotal));
}
```

and to calculate final bill

```
  private void CalculteFinalBill() {
    if(Percentage==0)
        Percentage=Default_Tip_Percent;
    if(!etBillAmount.getText().toString().equals("") && !etBillAmount.getText().toString().equals("."))

        totalBillAmount=Float.valueOf(etBillAmount.getText().toString());
    else
        totalBillAmount=0;
    tipTotal=(totalBillAmount*Percentage)/100;
    finalBillAmount=totalBillAmount+tipTotal ;
}
```

and I add these strings to strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Tip Calculator</string>
<string name="main_msg_billAmount">Bill AMOUNT</string>
<string name="main_hint_billAmount">Enter Bill Amount Here</string>
<string name="main_msg_serviceRating">Service Rating</string>
<string name="main_msg_tipPercent">%s%% Tip Percent</string>
<string name="main_msg_tipTotal">$%s Tip Total</string>
<string name="main_msg_billTotal">Bill Total</string>
<string name="main_msg_billTotalResult">$%s</string>
```

the variables are

```
 TextView tvTipPercent;
TextView tvBillTotalAmount;
TextView tvTipAmount;
EditText etBillAmount;
float Percentage = 0;
float tipTotal = 0;
float finalBillAmount = 0;
float Regular_Tip_Percent = 10;
float Default_Tip_Percent = 15;
float Excellent_Tip_Percent = 20;
float totalBillAmount;
ImageButton Im1;
ImageButton Im2;
ImageButton Im3;
```

when I try to add  setTipValues(); to Oncreate
and run my app I have a fatal exception

```
03-23 08:56:00.768 1836-1836/com.example.tipcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tipcalculator/com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity.setTipValues(MainActivity.java:48)
    at com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

in line 48 which refer to `

```
 tvTipPercent.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipPercent, Percentage));
```

I know butterKnife solve this annotation problem but how I can without using it?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvTipAmount;
TextView tvBillTotalAmount;
TextView tvTipPercent;
EditText etBillAmount;
float Percentage = 0;
float tipTotal = 0;
float finalBillAmount = 0;
float Regular_Tip_Percent = 10;
float Default_Tip_Percent = 15;
float Excellent_Tip_Percent = 20;
float totalBillAmount;
ImageButton Im1;
ImageButton Im2;
ImageButton Im3;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final EditText etBillAmount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBillAmount);
        final TextView tvTipAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTipAmount);
        final TextView tvBillTotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBillTotalAmount);
        final TextView tvTipPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTipPercent);


        setTipValues();

    }


    @SuppressLint("StringFormatMatches")
    public void setTipValues() {

        tvTipPercent.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipPercent, Percentage));
        tvBillTotalAmount.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_billTotalResult, finalBillAmount));
        tvTipAmount.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipTotal, tipTotal));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, which is the line throwing error for you? `MainActivity:java:48` refers to which line?

This error means you are trying to access a variable which is null

Please add the line 48 of your code which is throwing error; and have a look at [What is NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

---

**EDIT after your new informations**

I think your problems is in how you are initializing variables: in `OnCreate` method you call something like this:

```
    final EditText etBillAmount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBillAmount);
    final TextView tvTipAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTipAmount);
    final TextView tvBillTotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBillTotalAmount);
    final TextView tvTipPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTipPercent);
```

first off, you don't need the `final` attribute; but more important you are creating 4 new local variables, you are not using your `class-scoped` ones which are those:

```
TextView tvTipAmount;
TextView tvBillTotalAmount;
TextView tvTipPercent;
EditText etBillAmount;
```

if you want to use your class-variables you just need to call them without re-creating new ones, like this:

```
    etBillAmount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBillAmount);
    tvTipAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTipAmount);
    tvBillTotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBillTotalAmount);
    tvTipPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTipPercent);
```

as you can see, since you already created them in your activity, you just need to call them to get access.

That said, your error came off because you were not initializing the `class-variables`, but you were creating new ones. for this reason, the next time you try to access them, they are `null`.

Comment: line 48:        tvTipAmount.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipTotal,tipTotal));

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
tvTipPercen.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipPercent)+" "+Percentage);
tvBillTotalAmoun.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_billTotalResult )+" "+finalBillAmount));
tvTipAmoun.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tipTotal)+" "+tipTotal));
```

Comment: percentage ,finalBillAmount and tip Total replace placeholder in strings

Comment: Then you can directly set text on Textview.

Comment: tvTipAmoun.setText(String.valueOf(tipTotal));

Comment: You must convert float value into string

Comment: my problem when i try to add this code into method and add it inside oncreate unlike when i use butterknife i can add method

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Pier's answer with some Android basics, is `tvTipPercent` being **initialized**, for example `tvTipPercent = findViewById(R.id.tip_percent);` or something which is an assignment to those variables, before line 40 inside `onCreate()`?

If no (because you didn't post the full `MainActivity.java`), then it is very possible that the root reason is here. Assign them.